# Is the mock url generated for postman mock server always https?

Tags: postman, webapi, postman-mocks

I have a .Net Web Api(http://someIP:port/path) to handle HTTP POST request. I want to create mock server in postman. I followed [this](https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/mocking-data/setting-up-mock/) page, then I got a mock url like this:

> https://511d28ba-e0aa-438e-b226-a2a77dbf0d1b.mock.pstmn.io

I'm new to Postman mock server, not sure why mock url starts with "https" instead of "http" (my web api only handle http request,not https request). How to create mock url starting with http? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Found out that you can just update mock url by removing 's' from 'https' to change to http for testing. It works.